# print or miss string based on the result of simple math between fields of current and previous lines with awk

Tags: text-processing

```
1529.89 1.05    22.36   48.78   33.8
1529.91 2.05    22.36   52.79   36.93
1529.92 3.06    22.36   52.80   36.93
1529.92 4.25    22.36   52.79   36.94
1529.92 5.10    22.36   52.79   36.94
1529.93 5.24    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.94 6.05    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.95 6.27    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.95 7.01    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.96 7.26    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.97 8.11    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.99 9.22    22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.00 10.12   22.36   52.80   36.94
1530.02 11.26   22.36   52.80   36.94
1530.03 12.18   22.36   52.80   36.94
1530.04 13.12   22.36   52.81   36.94
1530.06 14.04   22.36   52.81   36.95
1530.10 16.21   22.36   52.81   36.94
1530.11 17.17   22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.12 18.09   22.35   52.81   36.94
1530.14 19.19   22.35   52.81   36.94
1530.15 20.19   22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.17 21.24   22.35   52.81   36.94
1530.18 22.05   22.35   52.81   36.95
1530.20 23.14   22.35   52.81   36.95
1530.21 24.14   22.35   52.81   36.94
1530.23 25.23   22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.23 26.03   22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.23 26.24   22.34   52.80   36.94
1530.26 27.10   22.35   52.81   36.95
```

I've got that type of file. What I need is to print every line of it if whole number in its second field is not equal to the same number in second field of previous line so on below two lines for an example:

```
1529.94 6.05    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.95 6.27    22.36   52.80   36.94
```

... I would like to print only first line and skip that second line. Second field numbers increasing up to ~1300 and decreasing to 1 after.

I tried awk using substr() function but it does not seem to be working as I just got stuck:

```
awk -F. '{for (i=NR;i<3814;i++) {i=1 n=(substr($2,4))}{i=i+1 v=(substr($2,4))} {if ((n+v)%2=1) print $0} {i++}}' test.csv
```

Comment: not clear at all. you are saying you need to compare each line with previous line then with your given two line example you compared first line of it with next line of it and printed the first one? so where did you compare that first line with previous line then?!

Comment: You say you have a CSV file but it contains no commas and your script sets your field separator to a period rather than a comma. You have about 50 lines of sample input but only 2 lines of expected output despite many lines that seem to satisfy your stated requirements. Please [edit] your question to clean up the inconsistencies, etc. - be clear and precise so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, your `awk` is of no help at all, it diverges totally from your expressed requirements.

- your field separator is probably not '.' but space
- to parse a decimal number you don't need `substr()`
- to round a decimal number to integer, just `int()`

So the code would look like this:

```
awk 'int($2)!=prev{
  print
  prev=int($2)
}'
```

To make it a one-liner you need a ';'

```
awk 'int($2)!=prev{print;prev=int($2)}'
```

The result is:

```
1529.89 1.05    22.36   48.78   33.8
1529.91 2.05    22.36   52.79   36.93  
1529.92 3.06    22.36   52.80   36.93
1529.92 4.25    22.36   52.79   36.94
1529.92 5.10    22.36   52.79   36.94
1529.94 6.05    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.95 7.01    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.97 8.11    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.99 9.22    22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.00 10.12   22.36   52.80   36.94
1530.02 11.26   22.36   52.80   36.94
1530.03 12.18   22.36   52.80   36.94
1530.04 13.12   22.36   52.81   36.94
1530.06 14.04   22.36   52.81   36.95
1530.10 16.21   22.36   52.81   36.94
1530.11 17.17   22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.12 18.09   22.35   52.81   36.94
1530.14 19.19   22.35   52.81   36.94
1530.15 20.19   22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.17 21.24   22.35   52.81   36.94
1530.18 22.05   22.35   52.81   36.95
1530.20 23.14   22.35   52.81   36.95
1530.21 24.14   22.35   52.81   36.94
1530.23 25.23   22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.23 26.03   22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.26 27.10   22.35   52.81   36.95
```

Correct ?

Comment: That's just excellent, exactly what I was looking for! Final line will look like that: awk 'prev!=int($2) {{prev=int($2)} {print $0}}' test.csv

Comment: @user531977 {statement}{statement} is correct but statement;statement maybe more readable. A one-liner is hard to read

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using `sed`:

```
sed -E '1p;N;/^[^ ]+ +([0-9]+)\..*\n[^ ]+ +\1\./D;h;s/.*\n//p;x;$d;D' test.csv
```

Using the `N;P;D` pattern you always process two lines at once. The long regexp is to find two lines with the same whole number in the second field, then continue with the next line, otherwise print the second line and continue. More detailed explanation on request.

If your field separator is tab instead of spaces, simply adapt the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6): second example

```perl
raku -e 'my @a = lines.rotor(2 => -1); for @a {.[0].put if .words[1].Int != .words[6].Int};'
```

OR

```perl
raku -e 'my @a = lines.rotor(2 => -1); for @a -> $a {$a.[0].say when $a.words[1].Int != $a.words[6].Int };'
```

The Raku code above is a rather-literal interpretation of the OP's title. Pairs of lines are joined using `rotor`, creating an overlap such that lines `0,1` are paired, `1,2` are paired, `2,3` are paired, etc. For every position of the `@a` array containing paired lines, a conditional is performed testing for `Int`eger equivalence of the second column(s). If the `Int`s are not equal, the first element (line) of the paired line is out-`put`.

One caveat with this approach is that `rotor` only returns fully-"grouped" elements by default. So any trailing "element clusters" are dropped from the `@a` array. The title of the question is *"...simple math between fields of current and previous lines..."*, but this answer enforces strict pairing (and the last line is unpaired). Hopefully this answer is useful in any case.

Sample Output:

```
1529.89 1.05    22.36   48.78   33.8
1529.91 2.05    22.36   52.79   36.93
1529.92 3.06    22.36   52.80   36.93
1529.92 4.25    22.36   52.79   36.94
1529.93 5.24    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.95 6.27    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.96 7.26    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.97 8.11    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.99 9.22    22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.00 10.12   22.36   52.80   36.94
1530.02 11.26   22.36   52.80   36.94
1530.03 12.18   22.36   52.80   36.94
1530.04 13.12   22.36   52.81   36.94
1530.06 14.04   22.36   52.81   36.95
1530.10 16.21   22.36   52.81   36.94
1530.11 17.17   22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.12 18.09   22.35   52.81   36.94
1530.14 19.19   22.35   52.81   36.94
1530.15 20.19   22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.17 21.24   22.35   52.81   36.94
1530.18 22.05   22.35   52.81   36.95
1530.20 23.14   22.35   52.81   36.95
1530.21 24.14   22.35   52.81   36.94
1530.23 25.23   22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.23 26.24   22.34   52.80   36.94
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'my @a = lines.map(*.words); my %seen; for @a[*].map(*.[1].Int) {   \
         %seen.=append: ( $_ => $++ ) }; for %seen.values.map(*.min).sort -> $a {  \
         @a[$a].join("\t").put };'
```

OR

```perl
raku -e 'my @a = lines>>.words;  my @b = @a.map(*.[1].Int).pairs.unique( :as(*.value) ); \
         @b.=map(*.key); for @b -> $a {@a[$a].join("\t").put};'
```

Briefly, `lines` are individually broken into words, and stored in `@a` array.

(First example, above): a `%seen` hash is declared. For each line's second column, it is converted to `Int`, and each `Int` becomes a key/value pair using the `=>` fat-arrow syntax, with the `Int` as key and zero-indexed linenumber as `value`. These key/value pairs are appended to the `%seen` hash. Because keys of a hash must be unique, multiple line numbers are added to the same `Int` key. Finally, data is out`put` by iterating through the `%seen` hash's `values`, and pulling out the `min` line number, and using that as a positional index `$a` to only print `@a[$a]` matching rows of the `@a` array.

Second example, above: each line's first column is converted to `Int`, and these are further converted to `pairs`, with the line number as key and `Int` as value. These `pairs` are then `unique`-ified comparing them on an `:as(*.value)` basis. The line-number is then recovered by overwriting the `@b` array with `@b.=map(*.key)` each array element's `key` alone. These `key`s are used as above to index the `@a` array of lines.

Sample Output:

```
1529.89 1.05    22.36   48.78   33.8
1529.91 2.05    22.36   52.79   36.93
1529.92 3.06    22.36   52.80   36.93
1529.92 4.25    22.36   52.79   36.94
1529.92 5.10    22.36   52.79   36.94
1529.94 6.05    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.95 7.01    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.97 8.11    22.36   52.80   36.94
1529.99 9.22    22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.00 10.12   22.36   52.80   36.94
1530.02 11.26   22.36   52.80   36.94
1530.03 12.18   22.36   52.80   36.94
1530.04 13.12   22.36   52.81   36.94
1530.06 14.04   22.36   52.81   36.95
1530.10 16.21   22.36   52.81   36.94
1530.11 17.17   22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.12 18.09   22.35   52.81   36.94
1530.14 19.19   22.35   52.81   36.94
1530.15 20.19   22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.17 21.24   22.35   52.81   36.94
1530.18 22.05   22.35   52.81   36.95
1530.20 23.14   22.35   52.81   36.95
1530.21 24.14   22.35   52.81   36.94
1530.23 25.23   22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.23 26.03   22.35   52.80   36.94
1530.26 27.10   22.35   52.81   36.95
```

https://raku.org